# android-Popup menu onitemclick error

Tags: android, popupmenu

I'm trying direct each popup menu item to the another activity by using intent,but i get an error shown below:

[image: error]

This is my java code of popup menu:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.one:
                Intent i = new Intent(Cihazlar.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            case R.id.two:
                Intent i2 = new Intent(Cihazlar.this,Kampanya.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                return true;


        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

And this is popup menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    androclass:title="Senin Dünyan" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/two"
    androclass:title="Destek" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/three"
    androclass:title="Sıkça Sorulan Sorular" />
```

So why am i getting this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check the package name of R in import statements.

Comment: Clear and rebuild your project again .

Comment: Can u post your import statements?

Comment: It didnt help,unfortunately.

Comment: okey im gonnna add

Comment: show your import statement with 1st line which is your package name ..

Comment: try to add this import ..
import <Your package>.R;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not at run time. It's compile time error. So if error is like `resource not found` then error is while importing `R` package or error in `menu.xml`.

But `menu.xml` looks proper, so I think, main problem is with `R.java` import. Check you have not imported `com.android.R`. It should be your `<package_name>.R`. 
And even if this is ok, then your resources are not compiled completely. There might be some error at some other resource file (.xml file)

The very last thing one can try is to rebuild your app and then check out

**EDIT**

I think error is in `menu.xml` file itself. Try below code, unless you have made some customize stuff-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:title="Senin Dünyan" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/two"
    androclass:title="Destek" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:title="Sıkça Sorulan Sorular" />
```

Answer (score 0):

bro have u declared it in Manifest plz post your manifest code